# The figure alongside shows the dispersion relation (i.e. branches of vibration modes) for lattice vibrations in aluminium (Al)

Tags: solid-state-physics

Can someone tell me how I can estimate the Debye temperature for Al
from the graph.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps [How to calculate Debye frequency from phonon dispersion curve?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-calculate-Debye-frequency-from-phonon-dispersion-curve) and the links therein will help?